# How to Fetch an array of strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I get a list of tag names from the server and fill `getedTags` with `data`.
my problem is `data` that it is a type of string while it must be an array , data value: `"["HTML","CSS"]"` but i need `["HTML","CSS"]` how can i fetch an array of strings and add to `getedTags` variable?

```
var getedTags = [];
$.get(getTagurl,
    function (data) {

        getedTags = data;

    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JSON.parse() from parse string to object.

```
var getedTags = [];
$.get(getTagurl,
function (data) {
    getedTags = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should convert the data you get from server into array. I presume the data type you are getting is `JSON`.

You can do `JSON.parse(data)` to convert in `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JSON.parse()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

It will make a javascript object or array out of string.

```
var getedTags = JSON.parse(data)
```

To reverse this, you can use JSON.stringify() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

It will turn your array or javascript object into a string.